# unexpected token '=' on array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to create a new array `var class = []` based off an array of arrays and comparing the indices within those. when i run the test it's telling me that the = in the `var class = []` is a syntax error. Not sure exactly what i'm doing wrong.

```js
function list(names) {
  var class = [];
  var array = names.map(function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (obj[0] > 55 && obj[1] > 7) {
        class.push("Name1")
      } else {
        class.push("Name2")
      }
      return class;
    }
  });
};
console.log(
list([
[18, 20],
[45, 2],
[61, 12],
[37, 6],
[21, 21],
[78, 9]
])
)
```

Comment: Dont use class...it is javascript reserved name...use something else for variable name

Answer (score 2):

`class` is a reserved word in javascript.  Change it to something else, you should be good.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use reserved words for variables..`class` is reserved here is the link for reserved words
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar